# Colocar un div debajo de otro usando css

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Quiero que el div de clase `banner` este debajo del div con clase `navbar`. He intentado colocando `possition: relative` a ambos div pero no funciona, cuando lo hago de esa forma solo me aparece el div de clase banner y ademas se toma todo el espacio del otro div.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/*
Theme name: Prueba
Theme URI: www.prueba.com
Description: Tema de prueba
Version: 1
Author: Alfredo Mujica
Authot URL: Direccion Web del autor
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-right: 12%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.topnav_logo{
 margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
}

.topnav_logo div{
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.topnav {
   float: right;
 margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 70%;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #C4D9AE;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.navbar{
  position: relative;
  float:none;
}

.banner {
  background: red;
  position:relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="topnav_logo">
  <div>
   Your Logo
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
   <a href="#news">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
     <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="banner">
  hola
</div>
```

Comment: Quita los float, están alineando los contenedores a lado y lado

Comment: No puedo quitar los floats, esos son tener el div de clase topnav_logo a la izquierda y el div de clase topnav a la derecha, estan estos dos dentro del div navbar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema se da porque los elementos flotantes no están definiendo un alto al contenedor principal con clase `navbar`.

Esto es lo que dice MDN al respecto de los [elementos flotantes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context) y el porqué afectan el tamaño de sus contenedores padre:

> Las reglas para el posicionamiento y limpiado de flotantes aplican
>   solo a elementos dentro del mismo contexto de formato de bloque. Los
>   flotantes no afectan la disposición de los elementos en otros contexto
>   de formato de bloque, y `clear` solo limpia flotantes pasados en el
>   mismo contexto de formato de bloque. El colapso del margen también se
>   produce solo entre bloques que pertenecen al mismo contexto de formato
>   de bloque.

Una solución que puedes tomar es utilizar el atributo [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clear) con valor `auto`. O también podrías usar el atributo [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/clear) con valor `both` (Es un *keyword* que indica que el elemento es movido hacia abajo para limpiar tanto elementos flotantes de la izquierda como de la derecha.)

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
/*
Theme name: Prueba
Theme URI: www.prueba.com
Description: Tema de prueba
Version: 1
Author: Alfredo Mujica
Authot URL: Direccion Web del autor
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-right: 12%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

.topnav_logo{
 margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 float: left;
 width: 30%;
}

.topnav_logo div{
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.topnav {
  float: right;
 margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 width: 70%;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 40px 15px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #C4D9AE;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.navbar{
  position: relative;
  float:none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.banner {
  background: red;
  position:relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="topnav_logo">
  <div>
   Your Logo
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
   <a href="#news">News</a>
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
     <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </a>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="banner">
  hola
</div>
```

*PD: Añadí el color verde solo para visualizar el ejemplo de forma cómoda.*